# making a div appear on bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

i have this div used as an information container on my page, i want to make a read more button on the bottom of the first div but cant do it, i tried position:relative and every other method i know to accomplish this but couldn't make it. any suggestion

```
<div class="main_banner" style="margin-left:46px;">
    <center><b><h3 style="color:purple;padding-top:2px;margin-bottom:0">header1</h3></b></center>
    <center><img src="images/pic1.png" width="275px" height="103px" /></center>
    <p class="index_services_p">some text</p>
    <br>
    <a style="padding-top:2px;float:left;padding-left:10px;" href="#" style="float:left">
        <img src="images/read-more.png" width="172px" height="32px" />
    </a>
<div>
```

any suggestions will be appritiated.
the goal here is to make the  always appear on the bottom of the main_banner DIV

Comment: `<center>` was deprecated around 1995.

Comment: There are some deprecated tags and invalid code here (div never closes?). This is either incomplete, or you don't understand the problem. I'd start with some code cleaning.

Comment: @AndrewClody only one div was missing, its complete on the source, i copied an example of it

Comment: It's hard to understand what your goal is.  It seems like there is a read-more button underneath the div to me

Comment: @ExplosionPills try again with the close DIV tag man

Comment: @Anton.P http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2vq/ -- what is the problem?

Comment: Suggestions... Use a stylesheet instead of sticking everything inline. Remove deprecated elements, such as `center`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills check it again, http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2vq/

Comment: I've tidied your code up a bit, and set it up over at - [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tiujv) Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't make sense to the question you're asking.

However you can align an element to the bottom of another element by placing the parent relative and the child absolute:

HTML

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum
    <a href="#">read more</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
div a {
    display: block;
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/VSUQA/).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML..

```
<div class="main-banner">
BLAH..

<a class="read-more" href="#"></a>

</div>
```

The CSS...

```
.main-banner{
position: relative;
//other styles.
}

.read-more{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
left: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
}
```